# Trying to replace bash arguments

Tags: bash, sed

I've been trying to figure out a way to take replace a specific bash argument with another argument in the same list. For example if I have something like:

```
/home/text.c /bin/mv {} ~/.trash
```

I want to replace the {} with the file I have, in this case text.c

So far I have this:

```
sed -i 's/{}/"$1"/g' "$@"
```

My assumption was that it would look through the arguments ("$@"), find {} and replace it with the first argument (/home/text.c). However, I only get back:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
/bin/mv: cannot stat '{}': No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BASH string replacement on `$*` which is string form of all of your arguments:

```
local args="$*"

echo "${args/\{\}/$1}"
```

Comment: I don't believe those backslashes are doing anything useful there.

Comment: Backslashes are needed since we are inside `${...}` try without backslashes and see unexpected output.

Comment: Ok, the second backslash is doing something. Interesting.